# Query as number parameter inside another query

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible (***in one query***) to get the result of **query_2** and put it as parameter to replace the number `7` in the **query_1** ?

```
query_1 : 

CREATE SEQUENCE  "SEQ_PK_ABC"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 7  ;

query_2 : 

select count(*)+1 from Table1 ;
```

Comment: You can try it out.  Simply replace 7 with your select query and see if it works

Comment: It gives me Error SQL : ORA-01722: "invalid number"

Comment: did you see my answer

Comment: Yes and it gives me an error , I edited it to the right working code , waiting you to validate it

Comment: I hope it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do it with dynamic sql.**

use like this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'CREATE SEQUENCE  "SEQ_PK_ABC"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH '||YOUR_NUMBER  ;
```